# Saving a file in OneDrive in a .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, office365, onedrive

I'm doing a `.NET` application in `C#` that in addition to other features, the user can log in to their `OneDrive` account and save a file to their account. I downloaded the code from the `Windows Desktop (.NET) guided setup` which teaches to register the application and do the authentication with the user and that part is running as proposed.  However, I need to know how to put the part to `save the file in the account`, the root folder of `Onedrive` (the user will only log into the account and then enter the file you want to save in the account and it will be saved in the root folder).  I've seen some examples in `GitHub`, but all for Web Applications.

**UPDATE**

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

public partial class App : Application
{
    private static string ClientId = "your_client_id_here";

    public static PublicClientApplication PublicClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(ClientId);

}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    string _graphAPIEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me";

    string[] _scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void CallGraphButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

        try
        {
            if (authResult == null)
            {
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(_scopes, App.PublicClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilentAsync. This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenAsync to acquire a token
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

            try
            {
                authResult = await App.PublicClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(_scopes);
            }
            catch (MsalException msalex)
            {
                ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
            return;
        }

        if (authResult != null)
        {
            ResultText.Text = await GetHttpContentWithToken(_graphAPIEndpoint, authResult.AccessToken);
            DisplayBasicTokenInfo(authResult);
            this.SignOutButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}

public async Task<string> GetHttpContentWithToken(string url, string token)
{
    var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
    System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
    try
    {
        var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, url);
        //Add the token in Authorization header
        request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return content;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

**REFERENCE:** Windows Desktop (.NET) guided setup

Comment: Can you share the code you use?

Comment: Okay, I already updated